# What is the nature of a hexblood's "irremovable living crown"?

Tags: dnd-5e, races, racial-traits

I have a question about the appearance of [hexbloods](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/706719-lineages#Hexblood) in D&D 5E. In their description, it reads

> Some who enter into bargains with hags gain their deepest wishes but eventually find themselves transformed. These changes evidence a hag's influence: ears that split in forked points, skin in lurid shades, long hair that regrows if cut, and an irremovable living crown.

In here it says that this crown (aka elder crest) cannot be removable... but can it be cut or destroyed, like a tiefling's horn?

Answer (score 5):

### The crown is a living, garland-like part of the body

The rules have this to say in addition about the nature of the crown:

> This **living**, garland-like part of a hexblood's body extends from their temples and wraps behind the head, serving as a visible mark of the bargain between hag and hexblood, a debt owed, or a change to come.

Other than horn or hair, it is described as both living, and as "a visible mark of the bargain". The rules do not explain what the consequences of cutting it off would be, but they should be similar to how the DM treats cutting off other living members of the body.

The crown also is described as "irremovable" in your quote, and it is explicity stated to serve as a visible mark of the bargain, so cutting it off to conceal your true nature of a hexblood is against the bargain. However, note that hexbloods do have an innate *change self* ability they can use to conceal their true nature for a time.

Comment: Going by the art on page 18 and 19, the crown looks like horns or twigs stuck to your head... I'm gonna say antlers!

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Yes, or a little like a crown of thorns